# TSQL relace a string text with variable

Tags: t-sql, variables, ssis

I am trying to replace the folder location in line three of the code below (Set @ProjectBinary ) to a variable.

The original code:

```
DECLARE @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max)
DECLARE @operation_id as bigint
Set @ProjectBinary = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\MyProjects\ SSISPackage_ProjectDeployment.ispac', SINGLE_BLOB) as BinaryData)

Exec catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = 'SSIS Packages', @project_name = 'DeployViaStoredProc_SSIS', @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary, @operation_id = @operation_id out
```

I have created a variable: 
DECLARE @Location AS varchar(250) = 'C:\SSIS\DWH_IS.ispac'

```
DECLARE @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max)
DECLARE @operation_id as bigint
Set @ProjectBinary = ('SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + @Location + ', SINGLE_BLOB') as BinaryData)

Exec catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = 'SSIS Packages', @project_name = 'DeployViaStoredProc_SSIS', @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary, @operation_id = @operation_id out
```

I keep getting an error:
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 61
Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any suggestions on how to change this to get the code running please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break it down as follows

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000), @ProjectBinary as varbinary(max);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @Blob = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @Location + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as BinaryData)'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Blob varbinary(max) OUTPUT', @ProjectBinary OUTPUT;
```

The line `Set @ProjectBinary = (..` can't dynamic or parametrised

Comment: Thank you @gbn .. it worked. Thank you for your help